# Making handleFileupload with parameter to share the methode

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

I'm using fileuplod primefaces. I have 3 buttons. Every button is responsible for uploading a file. My first steep is to use 3 methods on my bean to upload every file.
Is there a way to make the same method for all types? Every file has his own directory.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data"  style="height:125px;width:75px;">

                   <p:fileUpload  auto="true" 
                   fileUploadListener="#{composantbean.handleFileUpload(???,1)}"
                   sizeLimit="2097152"
                   label="Choose"
                   allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/"
                   description="Images"/> 
               </h:form>
```

On my managed bean, I'm thinking of this solution:

```
  public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event,int i) {
        String lienPDN =destination+"PDN\\"+FilenameUtils.getName(event.getFile().getFileName());
        File result = new File(lienPDN);
         try {
               FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(result);
               byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
               int bulk;
               InputStream inputStream = event.getFile().getInputstream();

               while (true) {
                   bulk = inputStream.read(buffer);
                   if (bulk < 0) {
                       break;
                       }

             fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bulk);
             fileOutputStream.flush();
             }

          fileOutputStream.close();
          inputStream.close();
          FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName()+ " is uploaded.");
          FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
          selcetitem.setLienPdn(lienPDN);
          } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                        FacesMessage error = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"The files were not uploaded!", "");
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, error);
                        }      
         }
```

Comment: And the question is..?

Comment: hhhhh..yes you are right ..My question is for fileUploadListener="#{composantbean.handleFileUpload(???,1)}" ????? What I write here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better way might be to implements three `handleFileUpload()` methods. Each can handle their unique code (e.g. passing the right filepath). From there you can call a `private void wrapUpUpload(String path, (...))`.

Most of all this keeps your code readable. If also prevents the need for changing the default implementation of `handleFileUpload()`.

**E.g.:** *make sure to replace `1`, `2`, `3` with something meaningful*

```
void handleFileUpload1(FileUploadEvent event) { 
    String path = "/uploads/1/";
    wrapUpUpload(path);
}

void handleFileUpload2(FileUploadEvent event) { 
    String path = "/uploads/2/";
    wrapUpUpload(path);
}

void handleFileUpload3(FileUploadEvent event) { 
    String path = "/uploads/3/";
    wrapUpUpload(path);
}

private void wrapUpUpload(String path, (...)) {
    // Upload the file
}
```